# "No supported glyph shapes table(s) present" [in OpenType font]

Tags: fonts, opentype

Getting these errors when running this command:

```
fontbakery check-googlefonts FontRegular.otf
```

> - dsig table
> - Monospace font has hhea.advanceWidthMax equal to each glyph's advanceWidth?
> - Checking correctness of monospaced metadata.
> - Checking font version fields (head and name table).
> - FAIL: head version is ('1', '000'), name version string for platform 1, encoding 0, is ('0', '000') [code: mismatch]
> - ERROR: Failed with AssertionError: offSize too large: 185
> - FAIL: Whitespace glyphs missing for the following codepoints: 0x0020, 0x00A0.
> - Font contains .notdef as first glyph?
> - ERROR: Failed with AssertionError: offSize too large: 185
> - FAIL: OS/2 sTypoAscender and hhea ascent must be equal. [code: ascender]
> - FAIL: OS/2.usWinAscent value should be equal or greater than 200, but got 0 instead [code: ascent]
> - WARN: Even though unitsPerEm (1000) in this font is reasonable. It is strongly advised to consider changing it to 2000, since it will liely improve the quality of Variable Fonts by avoiding excessive rounding of coordinates on interpolations.
> - FAIL: Font lacks "EURO SIGN" character (unicode: 0x20AC)
> - Font has old ttfautohint applied?
> - WARN: OS/2 VendorID value 'XXXX' is not a known registered id. You should set it to your own 4 character code, and register that code with Microsoft at https://www.microsoft.com/typography/links/vendorlist.aspx [code: unknown]
> - FAIL: Style name used in "FontRegular.otf" is not canonical. You should rebuild the font
>     Checking with ots-sanitize.
> - FAIL: ots-sanitize returned an error code (1). Output follows:
>
>   - WARNING: bad search range
>   - WARNING: bad range shift
>   - WARNING: Table directory is not correctly ordered
>   - WARNING: name: name records are not sorted.
>   - WARNING: name: name records are not sorted.
>   - ERROR: no supported glyph shapes table(s) present
>   - Failed to sanitize file!

The main one is that last one. It also seems to have something to do with [this other error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54264351/validating-opentype-font-issues) I'm having (from the Mac validator):

> kATSFontTestMessageTextKey sfnt: The font contains 'sfnt' data but no recognizable glyph data.

I'm not sure if this is because my glyph definitions are not fully correct, or what. Because I do have glyphs in the `CFF2` table. Or maybe I need to have the `glyf` table instead or in addition to the `CFF2` table. Any help would be appreciated. I have the glyph data in the [CharStrings INDEX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/cff2#8-charstrings-index). *I have to ask*: I'm not even sure CFF2 works. Would be interested to know if it does actually work or I should be using TTF instead, or just CFF.

Also would be helpful to know what that one means:

> Monospace font has hhea.advanceWidthMax equal to each glyph's advanceWidth?

The code I am using comes from [OpenType.js](https://github.com/opentypejs/opentype.js/tree/master/src/tables). I added support for CFF2. I ported OpenType.js to be 1 >3000-line file. But all this should not be too helpful since what's key is the output. I am basically wondering what output I should have vs. what I do have.

Comment: all those WARNING are pretty bad, too, so you'll want to get that sorted. Can you explain how you _got_ this font?

Comment: I tried creating it myself by looking at the spec. But some things are off and it's difficult to debug.

Comment: Hoping you have some thoughts or suggestions on the meaning of `no supported glyph shapes table(s) present` or `sfnt: The font contains 'sfnt' data but no recognizable glyph data.`, because I do have glyphs in the CFF2 table, but i don't know if it's formatted correctly or if i need to be using the `glyf` table instead, or what.

Comment: created it yourself _how_? Are you literally writing out bytes, or are you doing something a little more sensible like having TTX or the like do the compiling so that offsets, glyphids, SFNT tag ordering etc. are guaranteed supposed to be correct

Comment: Yeah I have some javascript writing it out.

Comment: That's doesn't actually tell us much. Did you write some JS from scratch that just turns arrays of numbers into actual bytes (i.e. are _you_ causing the bugs), did you write the JS to do some compiling for you (i.e. is _your code_ causing the bugs), are you using someone else's code like my minimal font building (i.e. are you using that correctly, or does maybe _that_ have a bug), can you please add a reasonably detailed explanation of what you're doing so that people can comment on what might be going wrong? Right now my advice is simply "remove name table, TTX->XML, edit that, TTX->otf"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187132/discussion-between-user10869858-and-mike-pomax-kamermans).